# How do I convert ARGB_8888 image in Android to a Mat in Native OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have an Image loaded as a Bitmap(config: ARGB_8888) in Android.

How do I convert it into a cv::Mat in Native OpenCV(C++) using JNI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method to do that in the opencv android library. 
Check org.opencv.android package. 
In the Utils.java, there is bitmapToMat method, and it is implmented using its own Native Code. Then you can pass the Mat to jni by Mat.getNativeObjAddr().

Comment: How do I again convert it into native cv::Mat in C++ from this?

Answer (score 1):

If u have the opencv libraries for android installed then do it like isHwang has said.
Example:
// MatToBitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
android.MatToBitmap(mat, bmp);
```

// BitmapToMat

```
mat = android.BitmapToMat(bmp);
```